# How to display list item name in fragment textview

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

**I want to show list item name in fragment textview.**

How can I do this?

Here is my code:

1. **Title.java**

   ```
    public class Title extends AppCompatActivity implements          OnVersionNameSelectionChangeListener{
   private static final String TAG = Title.class.getSimpleName();

   String str, arr[];
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
   getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
           WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

   setContentView(R.layout.activity_title);
   str = getIntent().getExtras().getString("string","defaultValue");
   //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), str , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

   // Check whether the Activity is using the layout verison with the fragment_container
   // FrameLayout and if so we must add the first fragment

   if (findViewById(R.id.fragment_container) != null){

       // However if we are being restored from a previous state, then we don't
       // need to do anything and should return or we could end up with overlapping Fragments
       if (savedInstanceState != null){
           return;
       }

       // Create an Instance of Fragment
       VersionsFragment versionsFragment = new VersionsFragment();
       Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
       bundle.putString("key", str);
       //versionsFragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
       versionsFragment.setArguments(bundle);
                                                                                       getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, versionsFragment).commit();
   }
   }

    @Override
   public void OnSelectionChanged(int versionNameIndex, String[] answer) {
   DescriptionFragment descriptionFragment = (DescriptionFragment) getFragmentManager()
           .findFragmentById(R.id.version_description);

   if (descriptionFragment != null){
       // If description is available, we are in two pane layout
       // so we call the method in DescriptionFragment to update its content
       // Bundle args = new Bundle();
       // args.putString("key", str);
       // args.putStringArray("answer", answer );
       //args.putInt(DescriptionFragment.KEY_POSITION,versionNameIndex);
       //descriptionFragment.setArguments(args);
       setArray(answer);
       //setStr(str);
       descriptionFragment.setDescription(versionNameIndex);
   } else {
       DescriptionFragment newDescriptionFragment = new DescriptionFragment();
       Bundle args = new Bundle();
       //args.putString("key", str);
       //args.putStringArray("answer", answer );
       setArray(answer);
       args.putInt(DescriptionFragment.KEY_POSITION,versionNameIndex);

       newDescriptionFragment.setArguments(args);
       FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

       // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
       // and add the transaction to the backStack so the User can navigate back
       fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container,newDescriptionFragment);
       fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
       fragmentTransaction.commit();
   }
       }
      public String getStr(){
      return str;
       }

       public void setArray(String[] s)
       {
          arr = s;
   //Log.d(TAG, "setArray: " + arr[0]);
       }

      public String[] getArray(){
      return arr;
      }
      }
   ```
2. **DescriptionFragment.java**

   ```
   public class DescriptionFragment extends Fragment {
   private static final String TAG = DescriptionFragment.class.getSimpleName();
   final static String KEY_POSITION = "position";
   int mCurrentPosition = -1;
   String[] mVersionTitle;
   String[] mVersionDescriptions;
   TextView mVersionTitleTextView;
   TextView mVersionDescriptionTextView;

   public DescriptionFragment() {

   }

   @Override
   public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
       Title t = (Title) getActivity();
       mVersionDescriptions = t.getArray();
       //Log.d(TAG , "onActivityCreated: " + mVersionDescriptions.length);
   }


   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       // If the Activity is recreated, the savedInstanceStare Bundle isn't empty
       // we restore the previous version name selection set by the Bundle.
       // This is necessary when in two pane layout

       String strtext = getArguments().getString("title");

       if (savedInstanceState != null) {
           mCurrentPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(KEY_POSITION);
           //Log.d(TAG, "Show last click position: "+ KEY_POSITION);
       }
               View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_description, container, false);
               mVersionTitleTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView_Title);
               mVersionTitleTextView.setText(strtext);
               mVersionDescriptionTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.version_description);
               return view;
   }


   @Override
   public void onStart() {
       super.onStart();
       Bundle args = new Bundle();
       args = getArguments();


       if (args != null) {
           // Set description based on argument passed in
         //  setTitle(args.getInt(KEY_POSITION));
           setDescription(args.getInt(KEY_POSITION));

       } else if (mCurrentPosition != -1) {
           // Set description based on savedInstanceState defined during onCreateView()
          // setTitle(mCurrentPosition);
           setDescription(mCurrentPosition);
       }
   }

   public void setDescription(int descriptionIndex) {
       Title t = (Title) getActivity();
      // mVersionTitle = t.getArray();
       mVersionDescriptions = t.getArray();
       //mVersionTitleTextView.setText(mVersionTitle[descriptionIndex]);
       mVersionDescriptionTextView.setText(mVersionDescriptions[descriptionIndex]);
       mCurrentPosition = descriptionIndex;
       Log.d(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState: " + mCurrentPosition);
   }

   @Override
   public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
       super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

       // Save the current description selection in case we need to recreate the fragment
       outState.putInt(KEY_POSITION, mCurrentPosition);
       //Log.d(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState: " + mCurrentPosition);
         }
       }
   ```
3. **versionFragment.java**

   ```
     public class VersionsFragment extends ListFragment {
     private static final String TAG = VersionsFragment.class.getSimpleName();
     String[] title = new String[0];
     String[] description = new String[0];
     String table=new String();
     public VersionsFragment() {
     }


    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

   String myValue = this.getArguments().getString("key");

   Title q = (Title) getActivity();
   table = q.getStr();
   //Log.d(TAG, "onActivityCreated: " + table);

   if(table.equals("Paragraph Writing"))
       table="paragraph";
   else if(table.equals("Story Writing"))
       table="story";
   table = table.toLowerCase();
   new MyTask().execute();
   }

   class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String[]> {

   @Override
   protected String[] doInBackground(String... params) {
       String[] versionName = new String[0];
       ArrayList<String> scripts = new ArrayList<String>();
       ArrayList<String> scripts2 = new ArrayList<String>();
       try {
           //Log.d(VersionsFragment.class.getSimpleName(),"http://192.168.1.105/android/phpcall.php?table="+table );
           URL url = new URL("http://192.168.1.6/ps/phpcall.php?table="+table);
           HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
           String strJson = "";
           String line;
           BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
           while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
               strJson += line;
           }
           //Log.d(VersionsFragment.class.getSimpleName(), "JSON string =" + strJson);
           JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(strJson);
           //JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(strJson);
           // Getting JSON Array node
           //JSONArray jArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray(strJson);

           for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {

               JSONObject jObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

               String name = jObject.getInt("id") + ". " + jObject.getString("title");
               scripts.add(name);

               Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
               bundle.putString("title", name);
               // set Fragmentclass Arguments
               DescriptionFragment fragobj = new DescriptionFragment();
               fragobj.setArguments(bundle);

               String name2 = jObject.getString("description");
               scripts2.add(name2);
           }
           versionName = scripts.toArray(new String[scripts.size()]);
          // title = scripts.toArray(new String[scripts.size()]);
           description = scripts2.toArray(new String[scripts.size()]);

       } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       } catch (JSONException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
       return versionName;
   }

   protected void onPostExecute(String[] result){
       //for(int i=0;i<result.length;i++)
           //Log.d(VersionsFragment.class.getSimpleName(), result[i]);
       ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, result);
       setListAdapter(adapter);
   }
   }

   @Override
   public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
   OnVersionNameSelectionChangeListener listener = (OnVersionNameSelectionChangeListener) getActivity();
   listener.OnSelectionChanged(position,description);
       }
   }
   ```